# Infinitesimal Form of Internal Energy

Tags: thermodynamics

The differential form of internal energy is the following
$$dE = TdS - PdV + \mu dN$$

But I naively think that this is inconsistent. Because when I do the following calculation I found it different.
$$E = W + Q$$
$$dE = dQ + dW$$
$$dE = TdS - PdV - VdP$$

So where does the other term come from? Furthermore how the last term disapear?

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics#State_functional_formulation_for_infinitesimal_processes

Comment: Since when is W equal to PV????

Comment: I read the article, and I understand the concept of true differential concept. But I am still confused @Charlie. So can we say then that W is path dependent and is not a true differencial, so it represent only the infinitesimal change?

Comment: Oh, you are right @ChetMiller ! Thanks, it is equal to $W = - \int p dV$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first law is given by
$$dU=\delta Q+\delta W$$
or with help of $\delta W=-pdV$ and $\delta Q=TdS$,
$$dU=TdS-pdV$$

which is for system where number of particles remain same.

If you add a particle to a system, then the internal energy will change by an amount which is called chemical potential $\mu$. Thus the first and second law of thermodynamics expressed above must, in the case of changing  numbers of particle, be modified to contain an extra term, so that
$$dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN$$

Comment: Thanks, that is really a clear answer and explanation.